# Tokbox video - Video is pixelated with no clarity

Tags: android, react-native, opentok, tokbox

I am evaluating tokbox for react-native for a support application which has video streaming.

The basic video streaming is working fine, however the clarity on the video is very unclear. It appears that autofocus is not working.

I am able to reproduce the same issue on the example application provided @ https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native-samples/tree/master/BasicVideoChat

The only change I have done is to add the app settings and back the back camera as default. The same code is available @ https://github.com/nitheeshskiploop/opentokBasicVideo

I have tested taking the video using **WhatsApp** and **Agora** and the video quality is good.

Below is my package.json configuration

```
{
  "name": "BasicVideoChat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "opentok-react-native": "^0.10.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The device information is

```
{
    "app_name": "BasicVideoChat",
    "build_number": 1,
    "bundle_id": "com.basicvideochat",
    "carrier": "AIRTEL",
    "device_country": "US",
    "device_id": "sdm660",
    "device_locale": "en-US",
    "font_scale": 0.8500000238418579,
    "freedisk_storage": 9232261120,
    "manufacturer": "Xiaomi",
    "max_memory": 268435456,
    "model": "Mi A2",
    "readable_version": "1.0.1",
    "serial_number": "unknown",
    "system_name": "Android",
    "system_version": "9",
    "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "storage_size": 3121049600,
    "total_memory": 3921362944,
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Mi A2 Build/PKQ1.180904.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/74.0.3729.136 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "is24_hour": false,
    "is_emulator": false,
    "device_uid": "cc60682ee481ec0f"
}
```

**Image from tokbox**

[image]

**Image from Agora**

[image]

**Image from WhatsApp**
[image]

Comment: Did anyone get solution for this?

Comment: No, I ended up using agora for react-native

Comment: Since you have used both opentok and agora, could you please tell which is best, cheap and reliable? I'm using opentok react native and it has a problem...please advise

Comment: Well pixelation was a major issue for our use case hence there was no case of making any other comparison for us.